# When I am creating a Stored Procedure it is giving me the query output rather than "Command executed successfully" in ssms

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms-2016

When I am creating a Stored Procedure it is giving me the query output rather than "Command executed successfully" in SSMS . And when I close it and open the created procedure again using modify option. The whole code gets disappeared. Any Clue on this?

Comment: Please detail how you are creating the procedure and what query output you are getting. Also what do you mean by closing and reopening the SP? Is it the SSMS tab?

Comment: Can you share your create script? My guess is you have some stuff that you don't realize. Reminds of a time when one of our devs created all their procedures for a project and forgot GO before doing a check and drop. As a result after running the application all the procedures were dropped because that logic got left inside the procedure code.